# MUI custom switch (IOSSwitch) sliding animation does not work when add onChange event

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, switch-statement

***Update: I have fixed the issue. The problem was occurring for having two versions of material UI. I have removed the material UI core v4. Now it works fine.***

I am using the  from Material UI. Everything works fine but when I add onChange event handler to control the value of the switch the sliding animation does not work anymore.

The switch ref: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-switch/#customization.

I couldn't figure out how a change handler is preventing an animation. This is just normal sliding animation. I have tried to add transition to its parent element but nothing worked.

I have used @material-ui/core.

Code Example:

```js
const IOSSwitch = styled((props) => (
    <Switch focusVisibleClassName=".Mui-focusVisible" disableRipple onChange={props.onChange && props.onChange} checked={props.checked && props.checked} {...props} />
  ))(({ theme }) => ({
    width: 40,
    height: 20,
    padding: 0,
    '& .MuiSwitch-switchBase': {
      padding: 0,
      margin: 3,
      transition: 'all 300ms !important',
      '&.Mui-checked': {
        transform: 'translateX(18px)',
        color: '#fff',
        '& + .MuiSwitch-track': {
          backgroundColor: theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? '#227BFF' : '#227BFF',
          opacity: 1,
          border: 0,
        },
        '&.Mui-disabled + .MuiSwitch-track': {
          opacity: 0.5,
        },
      },
      '&.Mui-focusVisible .MuiSwitch-thumb': {
        color: '#33cf4d',
        border: '6px solid #fff',
        filter: "drop-shadow(0px 2px 3px rgba(17, 23, 34, 0.14))"
      },
      '&.Mui-disabled .MuiSwitch-thumb': {
        color:
          theme.palette.mode === 'light'
            ? theme.palette.grey[100]
            : theme.palette.grey[600],
      },
      '&.Mui-disabled + .MuiSwitch-track': {
        opacity: theme.palette.mode === 'light' ? 0.7 : 0.3,
      },
    },
    '& .MuiSwitch-thumb': {
      boxSizing: 'border-box',
      width: 14,
      height: 14,
    },
    '& .MuiSwitch-track': {
      borderRadius: 26 / 2,
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.mode === 'light' ? '#D3D5DA' : '#D3D5DA',
      opacity: 1,
      transition: theme.transitions.create(['background-color'], {
        duration: 500,
      }),
    },
  }));

//this is how i am calling the switch
<IOSSwitch onChange={handleTemplateActiveSwitch} checked={isTemplateActive} />
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to control `Switch` state you need both `checked` and `onChange` props.

Here is [sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-sunset-p6nzwt?file=/src/Demo.js) of controlled IOS Switch.

Comment: I have used checked and onChange props. After adding that, the animation does not work.

Comment: I have used material-ui core. I have tried with material UI v5. it works in that. But I need it to work on material UI core.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not sure what you mean. Switch is a component from MUI core. I made an example for the last version - 5.14. Which version are you using?
Can you provide the full code example, with the logic of `onChange` handler, etc?

Comment: The problem have been solved. Thank you.